# Ruby warning: string literal in condition

Tags: ruby, warnings

In the seventh line, I get the warning, "string literal in condition".  What does the warning mean, and how can I resolve it?

```
   print 'Continue to use calculator?   Y or N'
   userAgree = gets.chomp
   if userAgree == 'Y' or 'y'
        userAgree = true
   else
        userAgree = false
   end
```

Comment: `user_agree = (gets.chomp.upcase == 'Y')`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change

```
if userAgree == 'Y' or 'y'
```

to

```
if userAgree == 'Y' or userAgree == 'y'
```

Or, cleaner and clearer in my opinion:

```
if userAgree.upcase() == 'Y'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` condition is not valid. This one works.

```
print 'Continue to use calculator?   Y or N'
userAgree = gets.chomp
if userAgree == 'Y' or userAgree == 'y'
  userAgree = true
else
  userAgree = false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make that:

```
    puts 'Continue to use calculator?   Y or N'
    userAgree = gets.chomp
    userAgree.to_s.upcase!

    def Check (ans)

    if ["Y","N"].include?(ans)
        puts"true"
    else
        puts "false"
    end

end

Check userAgree
```

Answer (score -3):

why not

```
if userAgree == ('Y' or 'y')
```

the syntax feels more expressive to me.

Comment: Because that's the same as using `if userAgree == 'Y'`. The expression `'Y' or 'y'` will always evaluate as `'Y'`!